# Pid and Lock files are not created in Nginx custom build Centos 7

Tags: centos, nginx, make, pid, centos7

I am trying to install nginx from source. After `make install`, I had a look at `/var/run/` folder but I cant find the `nginx.pid` file and `nginx.lock` files there. This is my configuration:

```
sudo ./configure --add-module=/opt/nginx-compile/modules/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.1-beta \
--prefix=/etc/nginx \
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \
--lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock \
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp \
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp \
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp \
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp \
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp \
--with-http_ssl_module \
--with-http_realip_module \
--with-http_addition_module \
--with-http_sub_module \
--with-http_dav_module \
--with-http_flv_module \
--with-http_mp4_module \
--with-http_gunzip_module \
--with-http_gzip_static_module \
--with-http_random_index_module \
--with-http_secure_link_module \
--with-http_stub_status_module \
--with-http_auth_request_module \
--with-mail \
--with-mail_ssl_module \
--with-file-aio \
--with-ipv6 \
--with-http_spdy_module \
--with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' \
--user=nginx \
--group=nginx

sudo make
sudo make install
```

After the above command, shouldnt there be a new `nginx.pid` and `nginx.lock` file created in `/var/run/`? I dont see them there.

This is the confirmation I see after `make install`:

```
make -f objs/Makefile install
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/nginx-compile/nginx-1.6.1'
test -d '/etc/nginx' || mkdir -p '/etc/nginx'
test -d '/usr/sbin'             || mkdir -p '/usr/sbin'
test ! -f '/usr/sbin/nginx'             || mv '/usr/sbin/nginx'                         '/usr/sbin/nginx.old'
cp objs/nginx '/usr/sbin/nginx'
test -d '/etc/nginx'            || mkdir -p '/etc/nginx'
cp conf/koi-win '/etc/nginx'
cp conf/koi-utf '/etc/nginx'
cp conf/win-utf '/etc/nginx'
test -f '/etc/nginx/mime.types'                 || cp conf/mime.types '/etc/nginx'
cp conf/mime.types '/etc/nginx/mime.types.default'
test -f '/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params'             || cp conf/fastcgi_params '/etc/nginx'
cp conf/fastcgi_params          '/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params.default'
test -f '/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf'               || cp conf/fastcgi.conf '/etc/nginx'
cp conf/fastcgi.conf '/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf.default'
test -f '/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params'               || cp conf/uwsgi_params '/etc/nginx'
cp conf/uwsgi_params            '/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params.default'
test -f '/etc/nginx/scgi_params'                || cp conf/scgi_params '/etc/nginx'
cp conf/scgi_params             '/etc/nginx/scgi_params.default'
test -f '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'                 || cp conf/nginx.conf '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
cp conf/nginx.conf '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.default'
test -d '/var/run'              || mkdir -p '/var/run'
test -d '/var/log/nginx' ||             mkdir -p '/var/log/nginx'
test -d '/etc/nginx/html'               || cp -R html '/etc/nginx'
test -d '/var/log/nginx' ||             mkdir -p '/var/log/nginx'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/nginx-compile/nginx-1.6.1'
```

Comment: The problem is that files are not created during the installation or during the execution of nginx?

Comment: The files are not created after installation. I thought these 2 files will be created after I run `make install`. Have I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, you are mistaken. Those files will be create by nginx when you start it. There's no point on having a lock and pid files for an application that is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically a pid or lock file is created upon start up of an application and not just by building the application.

As you can see from the `make install` output, that only determines that the base directory `/var/run` is there.

Comment: aha.. so I've misunderstood it then. I thought these 2 files will be created after `make install`. It make sense now.